# JavaScript, innerHTML not being recognised by javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code for my website:-

```
function HCreateWindow(top,left,width,height,zindex,parent) {
var handle = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000000);

if(parent==null) {
document.write("<div id=\"HWINDOW" + handle + "\"style=\"top: " + top + "px; left: " + left + "px;width: " + width + "px;height: " + height + "px; border: 1px solid black;z-index: " +zindex +"\" class=\"drag\"></div>");
} else {
    document.getElementById("HWINDOW" + parent).innerHTML += "<div id=\"HWINDOW" + handle + "\"style=\"top: " + top + "px; left: " + left + "px;width: " + width + "px;height: " + height + "px; border: 1px solid black;z-index: " +zindex +"\" class=\"drag\"></div>";
}
return handle;
}
```

It turns out that the innerHTML causes internet explorer 8 to say that innerHTML is null or not an object.  Thinking that this may be a bug with IE I updated to IE9.  Still have the same problem.  However, if I add the line before the 'if':-

```
document.write(parent);
```

it works, as if innerHTML is recognised.  Got no idea how the two commands are related.  The only thing is that I do not want to display the contents of 'parent', as this would make the web page untidy.  Any clues?

Comment: Are executing code when the DOM is ready?

Comment: What is the value of  `parent`?

Comment: Thanks guys - finding that it was browser incompatibility I resorted to jQuery. The DOM didn't have a chance to load, but there are different methods for different browsers according to window.onload = xxx. It works now. Thanks

Comment: I doubt it was browser incompatibility. Rather one browser was more lenient than the other for dangerous code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you call it inline when you document.write and AFTER the parent exists (poor name for a variable) it should work

```
function HCreateWindow(top,left,width,height,zindex,parentIdent) {
  var handle = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000000);
  var html = '<div id="HWINDOW' + handle + '"style="top:' + top + 'px; left:' + left + 'px;width:' + width + 'px;height:' + height + 'px; border:1px solid black;z-index:' +zindex +'" class="drag"></div>';
  if (parentIdent==null) {
    document.write(html); 
  } 
else {
    document.getElementById("HWINDOW" + parentIdent).innerHTML = html;
  }
  return handle;
}
```

so either

```
<script>
var hnd = HCreateWindow(10,100,200,400,1000);
</script>
```

OR

```
<div id="HWINDOWxxx"></div>

<script>
var hnd = HCreateWindow(10,100,200,400,1000."xxx");
</script>
```